# Can anyone help me with the name of a Sci-fi film about a robot apocalypse?

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

Does anyone know the name of a movie? I remember the plot of it.

So it's a post apocalyptic movie where robots are hunting humans and there is two main characters a man and a woman. And it turns out one is secretly a robot that is being watched by the bad guys. They are trying to get to a place that is rumored to be safe for humans and in the end it turns out that the safe place is a rocket that sends them to a planet with other humans.
And the bad guys are like, a hologram or something and it's someone famous but he was only able to be in re-shoots so he never interacts with other characters. He turns on the robots to kill everyone for some reason.
The movie is definitely not Terminator or anything to do with that franchise and came out in the last decade I think.

Comment: Could it possibly be a fractured recollection of "Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow"? There are robots, and Laurence Olivier was genned up out of the grave to be a hologram like character.

Comment: @OrganicMarble nope I remember large parts of it very vividly it was newer than Sky Captain and it had no other well known people besides the one villain and it was a lot closer to my description.

Comment: Figured it was a long shot, hence a comment rather than answer. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: "Birth of a nation"? Just scroll forward a couple hundred years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's [Singularity (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(2017_film)).

> Earth 2020, 3/4 of its households have a robot. The AI supercomputer, Kronos, considers humans the biggest threat to Earth. A century later, few humans are left. Calia seeks the last human stronghold, as does Kronos.

It's a low-budget Swiss-American film. Scenes with John Cusack as the evil mastermind appearing as a hologram were filmed afterward and edited in. (His name was the only reason I watched it on Netflix.)